# PostgreSQL create a new column with values conditioned on other columns

Tags: postgresql, insert-update, conditional-statements

I use PostgreSQL 9.1.2 and I have a basic table as below, where I have the Survival status of an entry as a boolean  `(Survival)` and also in number of days `(Survival(Days))`.

I have manually added a new column named `1-yr Survival` and now I want to fill in the values of this column for each entry in the table, conditioned on that entry's `Survival` and  `Survival (Days)` column values. Once , completed the database table would look something like this:

```
Survival    Survival(Days)    1-yr Survival
----------  --------------    -------------
Dead            200                NO
Alive            -                 YES
Dead            1200               YES
```

The pseudo code to input the conditioned values of `1-yr Survival` would be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN "1-yr Survival" text
for each row
if ("Survival" = Dead & "Survival(Days)" < 365) then Update "1-yr Survival" = NO
else Update "1-yr Survival" = YES
end
```

I believe this is a basic operation however I failed to find the postgresql syntax to execute it. Some search results return "adding a trigger", but I am not sure that is what I neeed. I think my situation here is a lot simpler. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more precise. Your version of Postgres? Are you talking about a one-time operation or a continued effort? Is performance crucial? Any reason you want to store redundant data instead of using a view?

Comment: @ Erwin, Sorry I have added the version to the question now. I use PostgreSQL 9.1.2. It is a one time effort and the reason why I want to store redundant data is that I export the database in .csv format to use in R or Matlab and I want the 1-yr Survival information to be readily processed and available as an additional column before I run algorithms. I do not know about views though, will investigate that as well.

Comment: I see. You may be interested in the addition to my answer about `COPY` then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The one-time operation can be achieved with a plain `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    one_year_survival = (survival OR survival_days >= 365);
```

I would advise not to use camel-case, white-space and parenthesis in your names. While allowed between double-quotes, it often leads to complications and confusion. Consider the chapter [about identifiers and key words in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Are you aware that you can *export the results of a query* as CSV with [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html)?
Example:

```
COPY (SELECT *, (survival OR survival_days >= 365) AS one_year_survival FROM tbl)
TO '/path/to/file.csv';
```

You wouldn't need the redundant column this way to begin with.

---

#### Additional answer to comment

To avoid empty updates:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    "Dead after 1-yr" = (dead AND my_survival_col < 365)
      ,"Dead after 2-yrs" = (dead AND my_survival_col < 730)
....
WHERE  "Dead after 1-yr" IS DISTINCT FROM (dead AND my_survival_col < 365)
   OR  "Dead after 2-yrs" IS DISTINCT FROM (dead AND my_survival_col < 730)
...
```

Personally, I would only add such redundant columns if I had a compelling reason. Normally I wouldn't. If it's about performance: are you aware of [indexes on expressions and partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html)?

Comment: Yes, the COPY option makes more sense I guess. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just have another brief question. What if I have a non-boolean X_year_Survival (as opposed to the binary one_year_survival) in the scenario above and I want to explicity label "Dead after 1-yr", "Dead after 2-yrs" and "Dead after 3-yrs" as the column values conditioned on Survival_days column? We cannot use: "SET    one_year_survival = (survival OR survival_days >= 365);" in this case. What is the syntax to explicitly label based on conditioning? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Berkan: `binary` != `boolean`. I suppose you ask a new question. You can always refer to this one, to save some typing.

Comment: Thanks, what I am trying to ask is if I want the possible values of the derived 1_year_survival (column) to be explicitly stated and possibly more than two labels instead of just TRUE/FALSE, what would be the syntax that I use? I don't think I should ask a new question for this because the definition and title of the original question (of this page) does not restrict One-Year_Survival to be a boolean column. (However I understand that you have suggested a boolean solution since it made more sense given the context.)

Comment: @Berkan: I added a bit to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, I think you are better off not storing data in the db which is quickly and easily calculated from stored data.  A better option would be to simulate a calculated field (gotchas noted below however).  In this case you would 9changing spaces etc to underscores for easier maintenance:

```
CREATE FUNCTION one_yr_survival(mytable)
RETURNS BOOL
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
select $1.survival OR $1.survival_days >= 365;
$$;
```

then you can actually:

```
SELECT *, m.one_year_survival from mytable m;
```

and it will "just work."  Note the following gotchas:

- mytable.1_year_survival will not be returned by the default column list, and
- you cannot omit the table identifier (m in the above example) because the parser converts this into one_year_survival(m).

However the benefit is that the value can be proven never to get out of sync with the other values.  Otherwise you end up with a rats nest of check constraints.

You can actually take this approach quite far.  See http://ledgersmbdev.blogspot.com/2012/08/postgresql-or-modelling-part-2-intro-to.html

Comment: This seems like a good idea.  Especially if this column isn't in one's source data (like a scientific study with a fixed dataset).  If one ever needs to recreate the database capabilities from source, a function seems like a healthy "reminder." Also, by saving the tablespace, the function (and hence logic) will always remain in the tablespace..