# Add column with the result of an OR operation on all other columns [SQL Server]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 100 columns containing boolean values. I'd like to add a column containing the OR result of all the previous columns.

Existing table:

```
ID, COL1, COL2, COL3, ... , COL100
1, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, ..., FALSE
2, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, ..., FALSE
3, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ..., FALSE
```

What I'd like to obtain:

```
ID, COL1, COL2, COL3, ... , COL100, RESULT
1, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, ..., FALSE, TRUE
2, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, ..., FALSE, TRUE
3, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ..., FALSE, FALSE
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184409/postgresql-create-a-new-column-with-values-conditioned-on-other-columns), I know this can be done hardcoding the names of all the other columns. Is there a non-hardcoded way of doing so?

Comment: The problem is, you're trying to treat a table as a spreadsheet. Despite their superficial resemblance, they're not the same. Rows and Columns are very different things in SQL. And the general expectation is that all data of the same "type", such that it makes sense to compare values or perform computations between values, will appear in a *single* column (spread across multiple rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql query for this. But I don't how efficient this would be.

I'm assuming the columns `col1`, `col2`, .... are in `varchar` datatype

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = stuff((select '+ case ' + column_name 
             + ' when ' + char(39) + 'true' + char(39) 
             + ' then 1 else 0 end '
         from information_schema.columns
         where table_name = 'your_table_name'
         and column_name <> 'Id'
         for xml path('')
       ), 1, 1, '');

select @sql = 'select *, case when(' 
              + @sql + 
              ') > 0 then ' + char(39) + 'True' + char(39) 
              + ' else ' + char(39) + 'False' + char(39) + ' end Result 
              from your_table_name;';

 exec(@sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL can do the trick by accessing the sys.columns but well... SQL is not designed for this kind of operations overall.

```
DECLARE @sConcat varchar(max) = ''

select  @sConcat = @sConcat +  + c.name + ' = ''TRUE'' OR ' 
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'MyTable' 
    and c.name like 'COL%';

EXEC (' SELECT ID, CASE WHEN ' + LEFT(@sConcat, LEN(@sConcat)-3) + ' THEN ''TRUE'' ELSE ''FALSE'' END RESULT FROM MyTable ')
```

Use the result of this to do whatever you need. I recommand you to create your RESULT column and put this into a trigger on INSERT/UPDATE for your table.

Comment: Well seeing the other response I'm wrong on using `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` going from `information_schema` is always a better idea but our ideas are somewhat the same.

Comment: Hi Lostblue, I found your answer somehow more compact. But you are right, better to use information_schema