# View new column conditioned on other columns in Django

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

With Django 1.11, I am trying to add a new column that is conditioned on other columns (as shown in the below image) and view it at front-end. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184409/postgresql-create-a-new-column-with-values-conditioned-on-other-columns) is the closest example but I would like to implement it in Django. How can we do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest implement this action on the migration file:

1. After you changed model, execute `./manage.py makemigrations`
2. Open new migration file in editor, content of this file maybe is similar as below:

   ```
   from django.db import migrations, models

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [('migrations', '0001_initial')]

       operations = [
           migrations.AddField('MyModel', 'A_islargerthan_B', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
       ]
   ```
3. Now you must inject your updater code by using `migrations.RunPython` :

   ```
   from django.db import migrations, models


   def update_A_islargerthan_B(apps, schema_editor):
       MyModel = apps.get_model('my_app', 'MyModel')
       for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
           obj.A_islargerthan_B = obj.column_A > obj.column_B
           obj.save()


   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [('migrations', '0001_initial')]

       operations = [
           migrations.AddField('MyModel', 'A_islargerthan_B', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
           migrations.RunPython(update_A_islargerthan_B),
       ]
   ```
4. Run `./manage.py migrate`

**Read more about [Django migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)**

Comment: Have never of this method before. It works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fxs7576 i glad that your question, answerd.